# How to filter Mailgun logs/messages by tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mailgun

How can I filter messages/log using `tag` in Mailgun API, ruby.

I'm setting `headers["X-Mailgun-Tag"] = 'sample-tag-here'`

```
RestClient.get "https://api:#{ENV["MAILGUN_API_KEY"]}"\
  "@api.mailgun.net/v3/#{ENV["MAILGUN_DOMAIN"]}/....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [Events API](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-events.html). As described in the [Filter Expressions](https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-events.html#filter-expression) section, you can even do some AND or OR logic, among others.

Here is an example for searching logs having `tag1` or `tag2`:

```
curl -s --user 'api:YOUR_API_KEY' -G \
  https://api.mailgun.net/v3/YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME/events \
  --data-urlencode tags='tag1 OR tag2'
```

If you are using the [mailgun-ruby](https://github.com/mailgun/mailgun-ruby) gem, you can do:

```
client = Mailgun::Client.new(YOUR_API_KEY)
events = Mailgun::Events.new(client, 'YOUR_DOMAIN_NAME')

events.get({ tags: 'tag1 OR tag2' })
```

Comment: I haven't tried yet, can I also do single API request with multiple message-id, e.g. ( id AND id AND id)

Comment: @aldrien.h yes you can, check the doc, put a link to it in my answer. for 3 ids you'll need parenthesis I guess (from what I understand from the docs)

Comment: last Q, i can't find a way to properly use paging in Docs. a bit weird, even single records returns "paging"=> {"next"=> "url", "last"=> "url", "first"=> "url", "previous"=> "url" }, how do I add in view and what are the params need? any idea?